# regexextract all groups from list as arrayformula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, re2

I'm looking for a regex arrayformula which would be able to extract all possible groups from a list. here is a visualisation:

[image: image here]

so far I tried:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6, "["&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A8:A)&"]"))
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6, "[("&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A8:A)&")]"))
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A5, "["&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "("&A8:A&")")&"]"))
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can fake it like this in B2:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A5, 
 TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(A8:A10, " ", ".*"))), TRANSPOSE(A8:A10), ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just a little out of the box maybe, but what if you tried in `B2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A$8:A,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SUBSTITUTE(A$8:A," ","*"),A2)))),""))
```

[image]

[image]